# When I create a new directory, create a markdown file with the same name in it

Tags: directory, automation, markdown

I want to create a lot of directories (manually, using the GUI).

I will then want to have inside them a markdown document with the same name as the directory, so this sort of tree:

```
624466
└ 624466.md
626665
└ 626665.md
```

How can I automate the `.md` file creation?

Comment: Tim, do you want to do this recursively under a parent dir or just a plain set of directories (no subdir) under a common parent or they are scattered all over (if so is there a pattern) ?

Comment: @heemayl non recursivley, just look at one folder (e.g. /home/tim/test) and as soon as there is a new folder (e.g. /home/tim/test/123) create a markdown file (i.e. /home/tim/test/123/123.md)

Answer (score 2):

I would use `inotify` API provided by the kernel to monitor filesystem events. There is no need for an indefinite `while` loop, you can use a tool that uses the interface provided by the kernel to check for any changes on any file.

One of the tools that uses `inotify` is `inotifywait`. From `man inotifywait` :

```
inotifywait efficiently waits for changes to files using Linux's inotify interface.
```

It is not installed by default, it is a part of `inotify-tools` package. You can install it by :

```
sudo apt-get install inotify-tools
```

The script i am taking about can take the form :

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
    parent="${line%% *}"
    child="${line##* }"
    new="${parent}${child}"
    [[ -d $new ]] && touch "$new"/"$child".md
done < <(inotifywait --quiet --monitor --event CREATE,ISDIR /home/tim/test)
```

You can send it to the background :

```
./dir_event.sh &
```

Or perhaps use `nohup` or `disown` if you want :

```
nohup ./dir_event.sh &
```

- `inotifywait --quiet --monitor --event CREATE,ISDIR /home/tim/test` is the command to monitor the file system events on directory `/home/tim/test`, we are only interested in `CREATE` and `ISDIR` events. We are saving (as `line`) and then manipulating every new line indicating a relevant event as they happen. Please check `man inotifywait` to get more idea.
- `parent` will contain the directory we are monitoring `/home/tim/test` in this case and `child` will contain the newly created directory/file. Both are achieved by using `bash` parameter expansion.
- `new` is addition of the two to get the absolute path to the newly created entry. As `CREATE` event will result in creating a file too we need to make sure that `new` is a directory.
- `[[ -d $new ]]` checks if `new` is a directory, if so then we have created the required file inside it.

Comment: I like this way +1

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for d in */; do
    touch $d/$d.md
done
```

Comment: Why not `touch "$d/$d.md"` and skip the `find`?

Comment: @muru $d.md might end up having bash look for the variable "d.md" instead of adding "$d" and ".md". Basically, it Just makes life easier :)

Comment: @muru That was what I was originally going to do but I figured it might cause problems.

Comment: No, it might not. Bash variable names consist "only of alphanumeric characters and underscores, 
              and beginning with an alphabetic character or an underscore".

Comment: @muru Ok, You got me :) Sometimes I forget these things

Comment: It certainly is no easier than renaming every file.

Comment: @muru You got me Ok? I rolled it back to the original.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've ended up using.

```
while :
do
    for dir in *; do
        if [ "$dir" != "Untitled Folder" ];
        then

            if [ "$(ls "$dir")" = '' ];
            then

                touch "$dir/$dir.md"
            fi
        fi
    done
done
```

Thanks to [@Grammageek](https://askubuntu.com/users/336615/grammargeek), his [original post](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/644810/1) really helped with the for loop concept..